# Need tutorial for mysql cluster configuration in ubuntu (lucid)

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, ubuntu-10.04

I am googling for mysql-cluster configuration steps in ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid). But I could not able to find good one. If you have any good tutorial could you please some one share with me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please let u know if you have any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a decent tutorial for Debian, and since Ubuntu is a debian-based distro it should be pretty close: http://thegioinguonmo.com/database-server/mysql/how-to-set-up-a-load-balanced-mysql-cluster-with-mysql-5-1.html

Answer (score 0):

Quick start guid from Oracle: http://downloads.mysql.com/tutorials/cluster/GetMySQLClusterRunning-LINUX.pdf